# Fail to install package when building docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, gdal

I use following code to add gdal to my docker image:

```
FROM node:7-onbuild

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install software-properties-common 
python-software-properties
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install gdal-bin
```

It always returns error when executing `apt-get -y update` after `add-apt-repository`:

```
W: Failed to fetch 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have added `--no-cache` when executing docker `build`.

Any idea about the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the node image is debian jessie based. The ppa you have added is for ubuntu different versions and not debian

[image: Ubuntu only]

Thats why your url gives a 404. You can check in browser too "http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages"

You need to find a debian:jessie ppa for the packages you are interested in

Comment: I find the package here: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gdal-bin How can I install a specific version of it? I am new to linux

Comment: Probably this is what I am looking for but I don't know how to fetch the package with add-apt-repository

Comment: I finally solved the issue with another ubuntu based docker image

Comment: Good, but btw on your first step in the Dockerfile, you could have just used `RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y gdal-bin` and that would have worked. No extra fuzz needed

Comment: I did `RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y gdal-bin` before but it ended up with a very old version, which does not support some functionality I have to use

Comment: Then you go with the other option or else you would need to build from source

Comment: So it means the gdal-bin on debian is not well maintained right?

Comment: Not like that, each distribution chooses packages based on their needs. Some choose latest and some choose stable/older version.

Comment: I see. Thank you!